# Reading and writing on and from named pipe

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, ipc, named-pipes

I'm trying out IPC with named pipes in a test application that I wrote for that purpose. I want to read a value from a pipe, but the reader doesn't seem to read anything.

I'm starting a server process and a client. The server uses a named pipe called `InitPipe` to tell the client a name for a new pipe for communication. After that happens, a new server process and the client get connected to the new pipe, the other server process and client get disconnected and the `InitPipe` reopened for new processes to communicate with the server.
The client writes data to the pipe and the new server process should read the data. That's where the problem is. The server doesn't seem to get the values off the pipe.

```
private void svr_task(string comPipe)
    {
        var server = new NamedPipeServerStream(comPipe);
        write("Com-Pipe: " + comPipe);        //'write' just writes to a TextBox on the UI thread

        server.WaitForConnection();
        write("Client connected: " + comPipe);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server);

        while (server.IsConnected)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();     //the program doesn't seem to run past this line

            write(line);
        }
        write("Client disconnected: " + comPipe);
        server.Dispose();
        write("Com-Pipe closed: " + comPipe);
    }

    private void cl_start()
    {
        //This is for InitPipe
        var clientInit = new NamedPipeClientStream("InitPipe");
        NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream("InitPipe");

        clientInit.Connect();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => stat_cl1.Content = "Initialize...");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(clientInit);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(clientInit);

        while (clientInit.IsConnected)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            client = new NamedPipeClientStream(line);
            clientInit.Dispose();
        }

        //This is where the communication with the server thread starts
        client.Connect();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => stat_cl1.Content = "Connected");
        reader = new StreamReader(client);
        writer = new StreamWriter(client);

        while (client.IsConnected)
        {
            string line = Dispatcher.Invoke(() => box_cl1.Text);      //read a value from a textbox (This works)

            writer.Write(line);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        client.Dispose();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => stat_cl1.Content = "Not connected");
    }
```

I want the server thread to receive the values from the client thread. The UI thread is not locked so that I can start another client, which can also connect to a server thread.
When debugging in VS and stepping through the code, it just runs after `var line = reader.ReadLine();` and seems to never get to the next line. So that's why I think it can't read any values from the pipe. But what do I need to change? I want to output the value with `write`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. It has to do with how namedpipes work. You can either be writing to or reading from a named pipe at a time. try not attaching StreamReader and StreamWriter to the stream at the same time. I got around this by a reader stream and a writer stream separate. Also, you can use the same pipe name for multiple clients, you just have to create a new instance of server after a client connects.